# How to make sure all threads pause when application pauses?

Tags: android

I've been trying to figure out how to stop all threads when my application is paused (when the 'Home' button is pressed) and I just can't figure it out.

**Here's what I have**: one main activity containing a tab host, every tab host has a list, when one item in the lists is clicked a new activity with details is started. Each list is within its own activity which starts an updater thread that makes sure the list content is always up to date.

**Here's what I've tried**: I've tried using the onPause(), onResume(), onStop() and onDestroy() events. The problem is that if I use either the main activity of the activity that holds a list to monitor for those events, they get called every single time an item from the list is clicked, as well as when the 'Home' button is actually pressed, so there's no way to distinguish between the situations.

Am I missing something? How is this usually done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty good indication that your design is flawed. You shouldn't ever have threads laying around that you can't account for or that don't finish themselves.

> Each list is within its own activity
>   which starts an updater thread that
>   makes sure the list content is always
>   up to date

This kind of thing should be done in a service.

> they get called every single time an
>   item from the list is clicked

This is how those events work. As soon as your activity is no longer visible (ie your new activity comes in front), it goes to onPause() and possibly onStop(). You have to account for this. You can't fight it, or work around it.

Comment: Ok, after some more reading on Activity life cycle and Services I figured out a few things: 1. you are right both about using a service and the calling of events on activities and 2. even if I use a service I still don't see a way to either stop or unbind the service when the 'Home' button is pressed...